# Is Azure VPN hosted Windows Server RRAS?

Tags: windows, vpn, azure

After setting up Virtual Network in Microsoft Azure, I can configure Point-to-Site or Site-to-Site VPN to allow on-premises computer to connect to that VNet. What is the difference if I set up a Windows Server in the same VNet and configure RRAS (Routing and Remote Access Service)? And if I would like to access Internet using both method, what configuration do I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the difference would be:

1. **Price**, Azure VPN would be cheaper for you on the long run compared to running your own VPN setup inside a VM.
2. **SLA**, 99.9 for VPN, while for VM they won't support the configuration inside it.

And Internet access is enabled by default once you create a Vnet or a VM.

Comment: Add capacity to that as well, different SKUs provide you with different throughput offerings.